# FusedLocationProviderAPI not receiving location if GPS is off

Tags: android, android-location

I need to run a service continuously to update my location data to server, I am using FusedLocationProviderAPI to retrieve location and priority as PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY, but when GPS is switched off no location is received.

I thought fused provider manages this based on the priority given, but that is not the case, can anyone tell me what can be done to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: If your `GPS` is off then you can programmatically on it and retrieve your location in `onActivityResult()`;

Comment: Am running this in service i don't think onActivityResult() can be called inside a service.

Answer (score 2):

Turning off the location on your device turns off all the location services. If you go to Settings -> Location -> Mode you'll see the location options. Switch it to "Battery saving (Networks only)" if you don't want to use the GPS.